# What happened to the chat rooms?

Tags: discussion

So, I put a temporary hiatus on my activity on StackExchange to try out Reddit. I go back, and this place had become a ghost town, even the factory floor.

**What happened?**

Answer (score 4):

Circumstances have conspired

The community took an arrow to the knee after a certain incident, that takes some recovering from. Coupled with the fact that over the past year the majority of our regular users have likely been working from home and have other distractions during the work day's downtime.

Comment: How's the Codidact site going, because it feels a bit stale to me, and I've been there: https://scientific-speculation.codidact.com/posts/281706

Comment: @Mephistopheles, It's hard work building a new community from scratch, it's nigh impossible to transfer one intact, though I wish them the best. Like many others I merely wound down my level of activity here without looking there.

Comment: I can try to be active on Codidact, but that would be stretching my attention to three separate forums. I'll try nonetheless.

Comment: What "arrow to the knee"?

Comment: @elemtilas Monica. The stack did change quite a bit after that.

Comment: @JBH --- Right.