# Where's everyone?

Tags: discussion, chat

Forgive me if this is such a dumb question. I don't wander around in the meta section.

I had a quick question about WB policy, so I went to the chat, [The factory floor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=worldbuilding.stackexchange.com) .. only to find out: *that place is emptier than intergalactic space, emptier than the QED vacuum*, and it has been so for months (if not for this whole year, or more, but I didn't bother scrolling up that much). Honestly, I only saw bots talking (feeds, etc) [I mean, in comparison, the chat in Physics, [The hbar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=physics.stackexchange.com), is way more active].

**So! Where's everybody? Do really nobody talk in the chats? Or is everyone now chatting and having fun elsewhere? Discord perhaps? Which server?** I wanna know! Pls pls! World building discussions in chat format can be fun to read and fun to participate, especially the ones involving physics. And, I have some free time nowadays. =]. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Could always be there on fridays, but to be honest, I don't know what to talk,about, really ^^.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happened to the chat rooms?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/what-happened-to-the-chat-rooms)

Comment: It's not good news I'm afraid.

Comment: @Separatrix Thank you for the link! Though, while that answers *what happened* (which is good, I was wondering what had happened), it does not answer *where's everyone* (which is actually what I want to know). Well, if everyone is in nowhere (they gave up chatting), that would be an answer too. A sad answer. But if everyone is chatting elsewhere, I wanna know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The site's changed a bit since the early days, back in late 2014. As with many Stack Exchange sites, there was a lot of excitement as the community here fleshed out its scope, and we did have a pretty vibrant chat room. But over time, the chat regulars left; many folks naturally drifted away, while others left after some events in the fall of 2019. In recent years, the site's maintained high levels of activity, but I personally feel like we've never quite regained those connections that make a community a *community*, rather than just a busy website. Correspondingly, chat activity has died down quite a bit. Some folks are still there from time to time, and you might have a decent chance of getting a discussion going, but it's certainly not like it was circa 2015 or 2016.

I was one of those chat regulars, and I'm not aware of an off-site server or other means of chatting. I'd be kinda surprised if there were one; I still don't think that we've regained the critical mass of chat-happy folks required to keep something going. Maybe we'll see the Factory Floor become more active in the future, which certainly wouldn't be a bad thing.

Comment: "the fall of 2019", in all possible meanings